# Why does Lovecraft write that Mount Nansen (approx. 9000 ft.) is 15,000 feet high?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

In the [first chapter of *At The Mountains of Madness*](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/At_the_Mountains_of_Madness/Chapter_1) I read

> the peak of Mt. Nansen in the eastern distance, towering up to its height of almost fifteen thousand feet.

[Isn't that height plainly exaggerated?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Nansen_(Antarctica))

Comment: There are other elements in this story that are also marginally fantastical

Comment: I expected the fantastic part not to change what has already been given a name in reality 

Comment: This range of mountains also contains individual peaks that are higher than Everest by 6000 feet. Since this story is set in *a fictionalised version of our reality*, there's no good reason that a specific mountain should be the same height as it is in real life.

Comment: @Enrico - if you havent seen them already check out the new illustrated versions of 'The Call of Cthulhu' and 'At the Mountains of Madness' illustrated by François Baranger = awesome!!

Comment: @wcullen, I think I've found them on Amazon. I guess the figures are not available online, are they? :P

Comment: @Enrico: 'The Call of Cthulhu' one is available here: https://www.amazon.ca/CALL-CTHULHU-H-P-Lovecraft/dp/1624650449/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=François+Baranger&qid=1606683745&sr=8-3

Comment: @Enrico: 'At the Mountains of Madness' here: https://www.amazon.ca/At-Mountains-Madness-H-Lovecraft/dp/1624650082/ref=sr_1_14?dchild=1&keywords=François+Baranger&qid=1606683799&sr=8-14

Comment: @Enrico: both I linked are the English language versions. The French come out prior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is believed he is referring to [Mount Fridtjof Nansen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Fridtjof_Nansen) in the Antarctica (13,350ft).

This is noted in *[The New Annotated H.P. Lovecraft](https://books.google.ca/books?id=9rF-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT951&lpg=PT951&dq=%22mount%20nansen%22%20lovecraft&source=bl&ots=WnENCWSAeA&sig=ACfU3U1E4wWuBqbUMw1HLKME2vpe_p9RyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHrIu58KXtAhWVq54KHVCbAOQQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mount%20nansen%22%20lovecraft&f=false)* edited by Leslie Klinger--see footnote #23

Comment: And the other mountains in the range that are taller than Everest?

Comment: @Valorum The question and response are referring to the uses in Lovecraft's fiction (although Mount Fridtjof Nansen is 13, 350ft). Safe to say Lovecraft uses some poetic license :-)

Comment: This feels like a retcon

Comment: @Valorum: Meh, if that's what the annotated edition says (I can't read it), then I'm inclined to say this is a valid answer even if it isn't terribly satisfying. You'll get similar responses if you try to ask how a raven is like a writing desk (which I believe we've discussed here before...).

Comment: It might surprise you to learn that in 1931, not every mountain in Antarctica was known, and even of the known peaks, their correct heights were not necessarily well known and the best estimates were not always correct.  This left a lot of room for authors to choose among different guesses, or just add their own.

Comment: Long story short, it’s very likely that Lovecraft just got the two Mt. Nansens mixed up, used currently available inaccurate estimates of its height, and for the “taller than Everest” peaks, just used his own speculations about as yet unknown or unmeasured mountains in Antarctica.  No retconning necessary.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Given that Lovecraft invented an entire mountain range with peaks larger than Everest, it's far more likely that they were well aware of the relative height of Mt Nansen and just used the name because of the recognition value.

Comment: I was disappointed when I learned that humanity never really found an Elder City in an unknown Antarctic mountain range that then had to be [nuked and explained to the proletariat as an underground test gone wrong](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/colderwar.htm)

Comment: @Valorum That doesn’t seem likely at all.  For one thing Mt. Nansen had even less recognition value in 1931 than it does today.  For another, *much of Antarctica was unexplored and even more unknown to the general public*, so of necessity, any story set in Antarctica *had to invent some geography*.  Postulating retconning just doesn’t pass Occam’s Razor.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Hmm. We have two significant choices. One, Lovecraft named his mountain after a *similar-sounding mountain* (but not one that is the same height that he mentioned) or two, that he named it after the one that he intended but changed its height to fit his fictional universe. Occam's razor would imply that the second choice is the correct choice (or at least the more likely) because the first option requires you to being a new postulate into the equation.

Comment: @Valorum  Your reasoning is fallacious because you continue to assume the Lovecraft had the same information that we have today, which has no basis and is contradicted by history.

Comment: I think it's clear from the text that it must be what we now know as Mt. Fridtjof Nansen - this is in the Queen Maud range, dividing the Ross Shelf from the Plateau, and the narrative talks about them seeing it after reaching that point heading inland. The other Mt Nansen is way off to the west of the Ross Sea, ten degrees to the north. Presumably he picked the name off a map as being in the right place and worked from there.

Comment: Interestingly, Amundsen [originally estimated it](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/27613#page/52/mode/1up) as around 15,000 feet, so Lovecraft was probably quoting an up-to-date figure here. It probably wouldn't have been resurveyed until the 1940s/50s.

Comment: @Andrew - That would make a superior answer to this one, or rather a superior source.